# Hadoop Map Program to Print Input File

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, reduce

So I have been trying to write a hadoop program which gets a input as a file which has many files and I want the output of the hadoop program to be just one line of the input file. But I haven't been able to do this. I also dont want there to a reducer class. If someone could help me out, it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You may use filesplit in your mapper to process only a specific file.

```
FileSplit fileSplit = (FileSplit)context.getInputSplit();
String filename = fileSplit.getPath().getName();
```